# Error 404 anytime I add image to Tinymce editor

Tags: laravel

Anytime I insert image through Tinymce from Laravel file manager, I get a 404 error. but without the images it uploads my texts perfectly. here is the script.

The site has been working well until I moved the files to another hosting platform. now I have been getting many errors of which this is one.

```
  $('#saveDraftBtn').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#save_c').attr('action', "{{route('adminTSelectedDraft')}}").submit();
    });

    $('#d_idd').on('click', function (event) {
        var cc = confirm('Are your sure you want to do this');
        if(cc == true){
            return true
        }else {
            return event.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#saveDraft').submit();
    });

    $('#edit_tread').on('click', function () {
        $('#save_c').submit();
    });

    var editor_config = {

        path_absolute : "/",
        selector: "textarea#tinymce",
        theme: "modern",
        height: 500,
        content_style: ".mce-content-body {font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;}",

        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
            'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
        image_advtab: true,

        file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

            var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
            if (type == 'image') {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
            } else {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
            }

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                file : cmsURL,
                title : 'Filemanager',
                width : x * 0.8,
                height : y * 0.8,
                resizable : "yes",
                close_previous : "no"
            });
        }
    };

    tinymce.init(editor_config);

    tinymce.suffix = ".min";
    tinyMCE.baseURL = '{{asset('assets/admin_we2/plugins/tinymce')}}';
```

Comment: Could you please add your code here?

Comment: The site is built on laravel framework. It has been working well before until I transferred the files to another hosting Cpanel

Comment: <div class="bks m-t-20">
      <label>Tread Content</label>
                                        <textarea id="tinymce" name="content_2">{!! htmlspecialchars(old('content') ? old('content') : '') !!}</textarea>
                                        @if($errors->has('content_2'))
                                            <div class="er">
                                                {!!  $errors->get('content_2')[0] !!}
                                            </div>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>